# Gemini Private API

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble accessing the private API endpoints using Swift. I have tried to use Python as I am pretty experienced and I am able to pull the data from the API. I'm not sure what is happening. The Gemini API doesn't have any Swift implementation in their docs, so it makes it pretty hard to figure out. I also tried to use ChatGPT, but I'm still having issue.

```
func generateNonce() -> String {
    let timestamp = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)) // Get the current timestamp in milliseconds
    let uniqueId = UUID().uuidString // Generate a unique identifier
    // Concatenate the timestamp and unique identifier to create the nonce
    let nonce = timestamp + uniqueId
    return nonce
}

func signPayload(payload: String, secret: String) -> String {
    if let payloadData = payload.data(using: .utf8), let secretData = secret.data(using: .utf8) {
        var result = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        payloadData.withUnsafeBytes { payloadPtr in
            secretData.withUnsafeBytes { secretPtr in
                CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA384), secretPtr.baseAddress, secretData.count, payloadPtr.baseAddress, payloadData.count, &result)
            }
        }
        
        let signatureData = Data(result)
        let signature = signatureData.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        
        return signature
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}

func base64Encode(payload: String) -> String? {
    if let payloadData = payload.data(using: .utf8) {
        return payloadData.base64EncodedString()
    }
    return nil
}

let apiKey = MyAPIKEY
let apiSecret = MYAPISecret
let baseUrl = "https://api.gemini.com/v1/notionalbalances/usd"
let endpoint = "/v1/notionalbalances/usd"
let account = "primary"

func performAPICall() async throws -> Crypto {
    
    let url = URL(string: baseUrl)!
    
    let nonce = generateNonce()
    let payload = "\(nonce)+\(endpoint)+\(account)"
//    let payload = "["request": "/v1/notionalbalances/usd", "nonce" : nonce, "account" : "primary"]"
//    let payload = """
//    {
//        "request": "/v1/notionalbalances/usd",
//        "nonce": "\(nonce)",
//        "account": "\(account)"
//    }
//    """
    
    let signature = signPayload(payload: payload, secret: apiSecret)

    var request = URLRequest(url:url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    request.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-GEMINI-APIKEY")
    request.setValue(base64Encode(payload: payload), forHTTPHeaderField: "X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD")
    request.setValue(signature, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE")
    request.setValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")
    
//    request.setValue(generateNonce(), forHTTPHeaderField: "nonce")
    
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    
    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        print("Response Headers: \(httpResponse.allHeaderFields)")
            }
    
    let wrapper = try JSONDecoder().decode(Crypto.self, from: data)
    return wrapper
}

Task {
    var crypto = try await performAPICall()
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Status Code: 404
> Response Headers: [AnyHashable("Vary"): Origin, AnyHashable("Content-Length"): 111, AnyHashable("Server"): nginx, AnyHashable("Content-Type"): application/json, AnyHashable("Date"): Sat, 30 Sep 2023 16:21:07 GMT]

Comment: Shouldn’t the url be the base + endpoint and everything else?

Comment: I am actually using the complete url in the URL request , the endpoint variable I have is for the payload, because its only the "/v1/notionalbalances/usd" and not the whole url.

Comment: https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#get-available-balances <- is the doc link for gemini

Comment: The docs state that that endpoint accepts a `POST`, not a `GET`

Comment: 404 is usually a bad url but I quickly looked and the only thing that jumps at me is post vs get

Comment: Tried the POST request earlier as stated on the docs, but still getting the 404.

Comment: Then you have an incorrect path and/or method. The docs definitely say POST and if you use GET when a POST is required, that would explain the 404.

Comment: Your payload does not look correct. According to the documentation it should be a base64 encoded JSON string. You are not providing a JSON string. Also, according to the documentation you need to generate the HMAC from the base64 encoded payload

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, but I did use a base64 encoded payload, I have a function  
  ''' func base64Encode(payload: String) -> String? {
    if let payloadData = payload.data(using: .utf8) {
        return payloadData.base64EncodedString()
    }
    return nil
} '''

Comment: I agree with changing the request to POST, i have updated the code above.

Comment: Get it working on postman, once you have it clear there is is much simpler to duplicate in iOS

Comment: No, you are base64 encoding the payload you send, but you are not base64 encoding the payload that you sign.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#private-api-invocation) it says that the `X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE` header needs to be
`hex(HMAC_SHA384(base64(payload), key=api_secret))`, but that is not what your code is sending.

You sending `hex(HMAC_SHA384(payload, key=api_secret))` and then you are base64 encoding the payload that you send in the `X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD` header.

Also, your payload is incorrect.  You are using `"\(nonce)+\(endpoint)+\(account)"` - which will be something like `<nonce>/v1/notionalbalances/usd<account>`, but it needs to be a JSON document.

The way you are creating your `nonce` also may not comply with the documentation.  It states:

> If you do not choose the option of a time based nonce, then the nonce has to be a number that will never be repeated and must increase between requests.

Although you are using the timestamp as the first part of your nonce so it will always increase, the doucumentation says it is expecting an integer (presumably in base 10), so I don't think a 160+ bit hex value will work.  It would probably be safer to just use the timestamp.

You also are going to all of the trouble to set up your `URLRequest` but then not using it.  You need to call `URLSession.shared.data(for: request)`, not `URLSession.shared.data(from: url)`

Suggested code:

```
enum GeminiError: Error {
    case signatureFailureError
}


struct NotionalBalancePayload: Codable {
   let request: String
   let nonce: Int
   let account: string?
}

func signPayload(payload: String, secret: String) -> String? {
    guard let payloadData = payload.data(using:.utf8), 
          let secretData = secret.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return nil
    }
    var result = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    payloadData.withUnsafeBytes { payloadPtr in
            secretData.withUnsafeBytes { secretPtr in
                CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA384), secretPtr.baseAddress, secretData.count, payloadPtr.baseAddress, payloadData.count, &result)
    }
        
    let signature = Data(result).{ String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        
    return signature
}

let apiKey = MyAPIKEY
let apiSecret = MYAPISecret
let baseUrl = "https://api.gemini.com/v1/notionalbalances/usd"
let endpoint = "/v1/notionalbalances/usd"
let account = "primary"

func performAPICall() async throws -> Crypto {
    
    let url = URL(string: baseUrl)!
    
    let notionalBalancePayload = NotionalBalancePayload(request: endpoint, nonce: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))

    let payload = try JSONEncoder.encode(notionalBalancePayload).base64EncodedString()
    
    if let signature = signPayload(payload: payload, secret: apiSecret) {

        var request = URLRequest(url:url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
        request.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-GEMINI-APIKEY")
        request.setValue(payload, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD")
        request.setValue(signature, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE")
        request.setValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")
    
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            print("Response Headers: \(httpResponse.allHeaderFields)")
        }
    
        let wrapper = try JSONDecoder().decode(Crypto.self, from: data)
        return wrapper 
    } else {
         // Throw an error
         throw GeminiError.signatureFailureError
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Job! the above code fixed the Status code 404, I now have a 200 Status code, but I am getting another error saying :  "Unknown error: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character '<' around line 1, column 1." UserInfo={NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0, NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character '<' around line 1, column 1.})))
"        There is no characters around line 1,

Comment: So when I put the data using Python I am getting a JSON file ->  [{'currency': 'USD', 'amount': '0.7605967176', 'amountNotional': '0.7605967176', 'available': '0.7605967176', 'availableNotional': '0.7605967176', 'availableForWithdrawal': '0.7605967176', 'availableForWithdrawalNotional': '0.7605967176'}].  <- its not valid JSON, since it uses the one quotation mark instead of two, like a valid JSON file. how would I convert it after I receive the request?

Comment: Okay, so it doesnt look like a have a valid 200 status code after changing my code to the above code -> what I am getting back from the request is.

Comment: Status Code: 200
Response Headers: [AnyHashable("Content-Type"): text/html, AnyHashable("Age"): 67911, AnyHashable("Etag"): "5dc6bbdccdd2100c4ca4b0155402db35", AnyHashable("Content-Length"): 172, AnyHashable("x-cache"): Hit from cloudfront, AnyHashable("Date"): Sat, 30 Sep 2023 19:05:03 GMT, AnyHashable("Last-Modified"): Mon, 18 Sep 2023 17:23:49 GMT, AnyHashable("Via"): 1.1 e7145a814fadc1f0b348d01cc9712f1c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), AnyHashable("x-amz-cf-pop"): DFW57-P6, AnyHashable("x-amz-cf-id"): q8fNqHf1AtjTm9sgkn7Q-V22MrP6vwj4VBHH6jBR1COvJSR9275ZbQ==, AnyHashable("Server"): AmazonS3]

Comment: I would start by adding `print(String(data:data, encoding:.utf8))` before you attempt to decode the JSON to see what they are sending. It is unlikely that they are not sending the right quotes. The json decoder is complaining about a "<" character

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am still getting then I print as suggested: I don't understand why its giving that as the data from the api.

Comment: "<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.location.replace("/rest-api/" + window.location.search + window.location.hash);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>

"

Comment: You are getting JavaScript that is trying to redirect a browser. You can see from the returned content header that it is `text/html`.  This indicates that you are still not hitting the correct url. Have you got it working in Postman?

Comment: Hey Paulw11, great Idea, I was able to get the request working in Postman, I had to make a few changes then I generated the signature and payload in xcode and copy it to Postman. It ran successfully.  But when I make the same changes to my other file and try to run the request I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What changes did you make?

Comment: I changed how the payload nonce was created. ->  you suggested this code -> let notionalBalancePayload = NotionalBalancePayload(request: endpoint, nonce: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)).  -> I changed it to only multiply by 1 instead of 1000 : ''' func performNotionalBalancesAPICall() async throws -> Crypto {
                let url = URL(string: baseUrlplusendPoint)!
        
                let notionalBalancePayload = NotionalBalancePayload(request: endpoint, nonce: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1), account: "primary"). ->

Comment: Copying and pasting the payload and signature work in postman.

Comment: I also noticed in your suggested code, you have the url = URL(String: Baseurl), not including the endpoint, is that intented, that might be the reason I am getting the error above, but I change it to the full base + endpoint url, and it says that my endpoint doesnt exist.

Comment: I copied that from your code. Your base url includes the endpoint path

Comment: your right, sorry. Still can't figure out why I am getting this ->. {"result":"error","reason":"EndpointNotFound","message":"API entry point `/v1/notionalbalances/usd` not found"}.  -> Im 100% sure I am using the correct API endpoint, I was able to pull the request via Postman and python script, using the headers from the Swift code.

Comment: See my edit - You aren't using your `URLRequest`

Comment: Your the best! Thank you! That fixed the problem!!!